# How do you set the text of an EditText menu item?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to set the text of an item in a toolbar menu with the EditText property. The textbox shows up on the app, but always empty. I'm trying to get "Hello World!" to show up in the textbox using 3 different ways, but it still is empty. Below is the XML:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/DisplayPath"
    android:title="Hello World!"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:hint="Hello WOrld"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.EditText" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find your MenuItem by id, then get its action view, cast it to EditText and set its text:

```
((android.widget.EditText)menu.findItem(R.id.DisplayPath).getActionView()).setText("Hello World");
```

Get the reference to `menu` inside your onCreateOptionsMenu() method, after you inflated the menu.

Answer (score 0):

just override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` like this in your MainPage.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**Edit**

you have to access `editText` widget to set text on it

Comment: I already have that function. The textbox is displaying and i can type in it, but it is empty.

Comment: but you have to access editText widget to set text on it

Comment: could you please post a screenshot

Comment: Cant post screen shot due to company policy. I created a editText, but the default values im giving it are not populating. I'm wondering if its because its in a toolbar and that causes the code to be different than with a normal editText.

Comment: the correct answer was what i said to you access editText widget to set text on it , i made a edit , can i get an upvote ?